# Telerik RadWindow does not fire ClientCallBackFunction after a ajax an __DoPostBack

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

HI,

I have a Telerik radwindow that allows our users to upload files.  When the user first opens the radwindow and sees the upload fields, they can happily select a file and upload it.  The window then returns the id of the uploaded file back to the parent page via the ClientCallBackFunction.  This function then passes in the ID to a javascript function that calls __DoPostback so that we can populate  the list of uploaded files.  First time around it works a treat.

However all subsequent times it fails to call ClientCallBackFunction unless i refresh the entire page.  I also note that any other control on the parent page to uses an ajax postback also stops the ClientCallBackFunction begin called, even on the first time.

any ideas?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

ClientCallBackFunction was deprecated and removed from RadWindow a long time ago, so I am not sure what is the exact version that you are using. 
Have you set DestroyOnClose to true? If so, try setting it to false and see how your app will behave. If this doesn't help, open a support ticket from your Telerik account and send a sample project where the problem could be reproduced so I could check it more closely.

Regards